# add newly created AWS EC2 IP to Ansible inventory at runtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, ansible, devops

I have a Ansible playbook "run-all.yml" like below:

```
---
- include: aws-ec2-create-instance.yml
- include: aws-ec2-install-software.yml
```

The first .yml will create EC2 instance, and the second .yml will install software for this newly created instance.

If I run each of these two playbook separately, it works fine.

My problem is, that I want to put these two together in one playbook "run-all.yml", so that I can run Ansible once to finish the whole process instead of two separate runs.

Then the IPs of the "**aws-ec2-create-instance.yml**" created EC2 instances, are not added to the Ansible inventory at runtime, then the"**aws-ec2-install-software.yml**" will be skipped due to no host found.

I'm trying to use the Ansible "**add_host**" module to add IPs to after instance creation, but it is somehow ugly. Is there a better way to add the EC2 instance IPs to inventory gracefully?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doable and I achieved it by use module "**add_host**" which can dynamically add host to inventory where inventory is **already loaded in memory**, key is to make sure the **groupname** is correct.

```
- name: add new instance to host group at runtime
  add_host: hostname={{ ec2.instances[0].public_ip }} groupname=tag_{{ item.key }}_{{ item.value }}
  with_dict: dict
```

Comment: can you please share that what you have in your `dict` just for idea? Thanks

Comment: just some key-value pairs, "item.key" and "item.value" of this dict is used in my command

Comment: @keypoint can you help me on how to write these hosts to a file locally